# Wave function of two identical quarks

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory, quarks, pauli-exclusion-principle

I'm asked to discuss what the ground state wave functions of $qq'Q$ would look like (a combination of two quarks and some spin 0 particle $Q$ which transforms like a singlet under flavor $SU(3)_F$ and like a $\bar{6}$ under color $SU(3)_C$). We limit $q,q'$ to $u,d,s$.

Since $Q$ can't be $u,d,s$ then I don't think there is a restriction on the total wave function of $qq'Q$, but if $q=q'$ then the wave function for the pair $qq'=qq$ has to be totally antisymmetric. Since we're in ground state, then $qq$ has to be symmetric in the space wave function, leaving it to be antisymmetric in $\psi_{spin} \psi_{flavor} \psi_{color}$. It can either be antisymmetric in one and symmetric in the other two, or antisymmetric in all three.

My question is this: since $q$ and $q'$ transform like 3s of flavor $SU(3)_F$, can $\psi_{flavor}$ of $qq'=qq$ be antisymmetric? Since $3 \otimes 3 = 6 \oplus \bar{3}$, could not $qq$ transform antisymmetrically like a $\bar{3}$? It just seems weird since I can't think of a way to antisymmetrically write a combination of two identically flavored quarks.

Comment: Good point, I've added that info in. $Q$ is spin zero, and I don't $qq'Q$ is expected to represent a physical particle, so yes, then the state is B=2/3. ($q'$ is not an antiquark)

Comment: The antisymmetric flavor antitriplet is (ud-du,us-su,sd-sd), while the sextet is the three combinations above with a + sign, augmented by uu,dd,ss. Of course, your color singlet will never be a flavor singlet.